# Exercise with a piece of code and x[2][5]

Tags: logical-deduction, computer-science

I was given this exercise to solve. 
It's beyond me, but important for me to solve this. 
The following piece of code is all the context I was given.

```
int[][] x = new int[6][6];
        if x[1][2] + x[1][4] = 20
        and x[0][3] + x[0][4] + x[0][5] = 15
        and x[2][2] - x[0][5] = 9
        and x[0][0] + x[0][1] + x[0][2] = 6
        and x[3][2] - x[3][1] + x[2][4] = r
        and x[0][5] + x[2][2] + x[1][2] - x[3][1] = 10
        and x[3][0] - x[2][1] = 5
```

then what is the answer of x[2][5] * x[3][0] ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to solve this as the code dosen't have a single `x[2][5]`

Comment: The sixth line currently reads "and x[3][2] - x[3][1] + x[2][4] = r".  I guess that the "r" here is a typo?

Comment: This isn't actually a computer science puzzle. The first line is a line of code, but that's really just a way of indicating  that we're talking about a 6x6 matrix, and that we're using C-style access notation. The rest of the lines are not code, but simple facts about the matrix. With that in mind, there may be a pattern here, but it's not a logic puzzle. That is, as Cool Guy said above, we have no information about x[2][5], and a dead-end line about x[3][0]. A pattern could be guessed, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Seeing people use `=` in if statements makes me cringe as a programmer.

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: This isn't a puzzle but a system of equations written in code form.  Solving systems of equations is a standard mathematical task. It belong on math.SE, preferably LaTeX'ed up.

Comment: @xnor Actually it's not really a system of equations as it cannot be solved in a purely mathematical way.

Comment: @dmg Oh, my mistake, I see that now looking at the answer. If I could change my close vote, I'd change it to too broad, as there's no indication of a nice pattern among the entries, and any array that fits the algebraic constraints is arguably correct.

Comment: @JoeZ. C and C++ background I guess? :D

Comment: C++. Other languages like Javascript and Python also use `==` instead of `=` for comparisons.

Comment: @JoeZ. Yeah, but they throw a syntax error if you use `=` in an `if` or another nutty place.  At least Python does.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is:

> (2*6 + 6) * (3*6 + 1) = 342

Why?

> Using $x[0][3] + x[0][4] + x[0][5] = 15$ and $x[0][0] + x[0][1] + x[0][2] = 6$ we get that $sum(x[0][i]) = 21$ and we can deduce that $x[0][i] = i + 1$. We also can find that $x[2][2] = 9 + x[0][5] = 15$. An obvious thing that can be suggested is that $x[i][j] = i*6 + j + 1$. Thus $x[2][5] * x[3][0] = (2*6 + 6) * (3*6 + 1) = 342$.

Of course, we can cross-validate:

> Here are all the equations:
> $x[1][2] + x[1][4] = 6 + 3 + 6 + 5 = 20$
> $x[0][3] + x[0][4] + x[0][5] = 4 + 5 + 6 = 15$
> $x[2][2] - x[0][5] = 2*6 + 3 - 6 = 9$
> $x[0][0] + x[0][1] + x[0][2] = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6$
> $x[3][2] - x[3][1] + x[2][4] = 3*6 + 3 - 3*6 - 2 + 2*6 + 5 = r$ // which kinda makes sense as r is the 18th letter of the alphabet
> $x[0][5] + x[2][2] + x[1][2] - x[3][1] = 6 + 2*6 + 3 + 1*6 + 3 - 3*6 - 2 = 10$
> $x[3][0] - x[2][1] = 3*6 + 1 - 2*6 + 2 = 5$

Comment: Great answer! Though may I ask how obvious the x[i][j] formula was? Because getting the x[0][i] relation makes sense, and I was about to find x[2][2] by myself. But I couldn't make the jump to your relation on my own. It works, but it didn't seem obvious to me. Is this a common pattern/trend in these types of problems, or were you yourself just able to see it as an obvious thing? Just curious in case there is any sort of thing I need to keep in mind if I run into these things again.

Comment: I can't speak for dmg, but the pattern is pretty well-known. It may help to write it out: x[0][0]=1, x[0][1]=2, x[0][2]=3, x[0][3]=4 x[0][4]=5, x[0][5]=6, x[1][0]=6, x[1][1]=7, and so on. It's just the pattern for mapping a 2d array to a 1d array.

Comment: @Brian_Drozd However,do notice the overlap of the rows of the matrix - x[0][5] = x[1][0].

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that this code is written in some programming language that initializes new numerical variables with 0.

Since x[2][5] has not been referenced / used / accessed / changed before your question, then its value will be 0 and also the product x[2][5] * x[3][0] will have value 0.

Comment: I guess that the language is Java. Yes. It does initialize array variables(`int`s) to 0,IIRC.

Comment: I don't know anything about Java, but when I look at it, it looks to me like an array of some sort. That is, each of the numbers 0 - 5 are variables.

Comment: No, it's not Java.